# django2 - A like button per post. Ajax to submit the like button form but I have many forms with the same ID

Tags: python, django

In my template I'm looping through posts and for each post, a like button is placed for each post and this is working.

I want the user to be able to like the post but I'm stuck and not really sure what to search for that might help solve this problem.

I have a single ajax function, I want to be able to capture the submitted form so I can capture post ID values from that form.  What seems to be happening is the first post works when I press the like button but the second post causes a page refresh and fails to fire the function.

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#like_toggle").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var id = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "/like" ,
                 data: {
                        'id': id,
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                       },
                 success: function(){
                     $('#like-section').html("sent")
                    }
            });
            return false;
       });

    });

</script>
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="like_toggle">
        {% csrf_token %}
               <div id="like-section">
                    <button id="like" value="{{ post.id }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 btn-sm float-right">+Like<span class="badge badge-light ml-2">{{ post.likes }}</span></button>
                </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

submit function is being called on the first form only, because it expects the id to be unique to it, instead set a class for all your forms and call your function on that, e.g:

```
<form method="POST" id="form-1" class="like-toggle">
...
</form>

<form method="POST" id="form-2" class="like-toggle">
    ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".like-toggle").submit(function (event) {
            // ...
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to avoid doing this but this is working as it makes duplicate script code.  In the template loop event, I just add the ajax click event script to the template including the tags for that specific post.  Confirmed this is working.

template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#like_toggle{{ post.id }}').submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var id = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '{% url 'like_toggle' %}',
                 data: {
                        'id': id,
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                       },
                 success: function(){
                     $('#like-section{{ post.id }}').html("sent")
                    }
            });
            return false;
       });

    });

</script>
```

form code

```
<form method="POST" id="like_toggle{{ post.id }}">
{% csrf_token %}
       <div id="like-section{{ post.id }}">
            <button id="like{{ post.id }}" value="{{ post.id }}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 btn-sm float-right">+Like<span class="badge badge-light ml-2">{{ post.likes }}</span></button>
        </div>
</form>
```